# Paper.js with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, paperjs

I'm trying to use paper.js with webpack using [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit).

Just for the reference, I had to install **json-loader** and **node-loader**, also I had to add node to webpack config, to get rid of the build errors like this

```
ERROR in ./~/paper/dist/paper-node.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /home/bojan/www/react/MyApp/node_modules/paper/dist
 @ ./~/paper/dist/paper-node.js 4808:3-16 10779:10-23 12253:10-23
```

This is what my webpack.config.js looks like

```
var config = {
  ...

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.node']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: "node-loader"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },

  node: {
    child_process: 'empty',
    console: 'empty',
    dgram: 'empty',
    dns: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

I still get some warning during the gulp build though:

```
WARNING in ./~/paper/dist/paper-node.js
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.

WARNING in ./~/paper/dist/paper-node.js
Critical dependencies:
12263:19-26 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/paper/dist/paper-node.js 12263:19-26

WARNING in ./~/paper/~/jsdom/~/acorn-globals/~/acorn/dist/walk.js
Critical dependencies:
1:503-510 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/paper/~/jsdom/~/acorn-globals/~/acorn/dist/walk.js 1:503-510

WARNING in ./~/paper/~/jsdom/~/acorn-globals/~/acorn/dist/acorn.js
Critical dependencies:
1:478-485 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/paper/~/jsdom/~/acorn-globals/~/acorn/dist/acorn.js 1:478-485

WARNING in ./~/paper/~/request/~/hawk/~/hoek/lib/index.js
Critical dependencies:
403:34-60 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/paper/~/request/~/hawk/~/hoek/lib/index.js 403:34-60
```

Also I get an error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot open /home/bojan/www/react/MyApp/node_modules/paper/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: TypeError: process.dlopen is not a function
    (anonymous function) @ canvas.node:1
    map../paper-core @ app.js:95332
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:19
    (anonymous function) @ bindings.js:2
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:19
    (anonymous function) @ canvas.js:12
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:19
    (anonymous function) @ paper-node.js:10243
    (anonymous function) @ paper-node.js:33
    (anonymous function) @ paper-node.js:12290
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:19
    (anonymous function) @ CbPaper.js:7
    Object.defineProperty.value @ CbPaper.js:146
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:19
    Object.defineProperty.value @ App.js:12
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:19
    exports.TYPES.INTEGER @ app.js:5
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:19
    obj.__esModule.default @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:39
    (anonymous function) @ bootstrap 62fa91d09bcc96ef0556:39
```

Any ideas? I am fairly new to the whole webpack/node ecosystem, so I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PaperJS build on npm is `paper-node`, which is the NodeJS version of PaperJS. It depends on `jsdom` and `node-canvas` which won't work in the browser.

I'm afraid you'll need to use bower to retrieve the client version of PaperJS, or link to `https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js` for the `paper` dependency in your package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
  "paper": "paperjs/paper.js"
}
```

Then require PaperJS via `require('paper/dist/paper-full')`.

As @bebraw points out, you can select a specific version of PaperJS by providing a tag. See the [Releases](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/releases) page. Since the current version is 0.9.22, the last snippet would become:

```
"dependencies": {
  "paper": "paperjs/paper.js#v0.9.22"
}
```

Comment: I would go with latter and fix it to tag `v0.9.22` (`paperjs/paper.js#v0.9.22`).

Comment: Since this pull request got merged, we're including other versions than the node version in NPM: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/pull/665 Once this is released, you should be able to use NPM also.